# Storybook requires default Ant Design component to be exported for styling to be applied

Tags: reactjs, antd, storybook

I'm looking to design some of my React Components using Ant Design and documenting them in Storybook.

Both the storybook and components are written correctly and working.

**modal.stories.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { action } from "@storybook/addon-actions";
import { Button } from "@storybook/react/demo";
import { BasicModal } from "./BasicModal";
import { Modal } from "antd"; // IF I REMOVE THIS ANT DESIGN DOESN'T APPLY.

export default {
  title: "Modals"
};

export const basicModal = () => <BasicModal visible={true} />;
export const basicModal2 = () => <Modal visible={true} />; //IF I REMOVE THIS ANT DESIGN DOESN'T APPLY.
```

**BasicModal.tsx**

```
import React, { ReactNode } from "react";
import { Modal } from "antd";
interface BasicModalProps {}

export const BasicModal: React.FC<BasicModalProps> = ({}) => {
  return (
    <Modal
      title="Basic Modal"
      visible={true}
    >
      <p>Some contents...</p>
      <p>Some contents...</p>
      <p>Some contents...</p>
    </Modal>
  );
};
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                test: /\.js$/,
                options: {
                    presets: ["@babel/react"],
                    plugins: [
                        ['import', {libraryName: "antd", style: true}]
                    ]
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                loaders: [
                    "style-loader",
                    "css-loader",
                    {
                        loader: "less-loader",

                        options: {
                            modifyVars: {"@primary-color": "#d8df19"},
                            javascriptEnabled: true
                        }
                    }
                ],
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, "../")
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

However I am running into an issue of having the styles apply in `modal.stories.js`. If I do not include `import { modal } from 'antd'` and export a constant using the `Modal` component, my *own* styled component will not have the ant design styling applied to it.

In the above example, I get two modals `basicModal` and `basicModal2` both having styled by ant-design. But if I comment out `basicModal2` the `basicModal` reverts back to default CSS styling.

Is there a way to fix this without adding a default Ant Design component in each story?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Import `antd` styles `import 'antd/dist/antd.css';` within storybook's `config.js` file:

```
// @ .storybook/config.js 
import { configure } from '@storybook/react';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';

function loadStories() {
  const req = require.context('stories', true, /\.stories\.js$/);
  req.keys().forEach(filename => req(filename));
}

configure(loadStories, module);
```

Refer to [CSS Support](https://storybook.js.org/docs/configurations/default-config/#css-support) at `storybook` docs.

Answer (score 14):

## Storybook v6

Go into (or create) `.storybook/preview.js` and add `import 'antd/dist/antd.css';` to the top.

---

*Example `.storybook/preview.js`*

```
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';

export const parameters = {
    actions: { argTypesRegex: '^on[A-Z].*' },
};
```

Comment: But how modify theme variables from .less file?

Comment: Didn't work for me. It still says:
ERROR in ./node_modules/antd/dist/antd.css 13:6
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (13:6)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders