# Storybook and AntDesign components - how to set-up with CRA & Typescript?

Tags: typescript, create-react-app, antd, storybook

I want to set up Storybook with components built on top of AntDesign components inside my CRA project with Typescript.

CRA - v3
Storybook - v5.25
AntDesign - v3.23.2

I succeed in setting up CRA + AntDesign, setting up Storybook, my AntDesign components render in Storybook with AntD css classes, but the styling is missing

I tried

- creating a *webpack.config.js* file in *.stories* folder and using configuration from [Storybook doesn't understand import on demand for antd components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51679614/storybook-doesnt-understand-import-on-demand-for-antd-components) and https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/3949/
- creating a *.babelrc* file and import babel import and ant there
- using the same configuration as decribed in Advanced AntD docs: https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-create-react-app

None of the approaches allows me to render the AntD component with styling

// .stories/webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        loader: "babel-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        test: /\.js$/,
        options: {
          presets: ["@babel/react"],
          plugins: [["import", { libraryName: "antd", style: true }]]
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        loaders: [
          "style-loader",
          "css-loader",
          {
            loader: "less-loader",

            options: {
              modifyVars: { "@primary-color": "#d8df19" },
              javascriptEnabled: true
            }
          }
        ],
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, "../")
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

// .stories/.babelrc

```
{
  "plugins": [
    [
      "import",
      {
        "libraryName": "antd",
        "style": "css"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

// my component based on AntDesign

```
import { Menu } from "antd";
import React, { FC } from "react";
import { RouteComponentProps, withRouter } from "react-router";
import { styled } from "styletron-react";

export const Sidebar: FC<RouteComponentProps> = ({ history }) => {
  const SidebarLayout = styled(Menu, {
    height: "100vh",
    width: "100%"
  });

  return (
    <SidebarLayout
      onSelect={item => {
        history.push(item.key);
      }}
      defaultSelectedKeys={["/"]}
      selectedKeys={[history.location.pathname]}
      mode="inline"
      theme="dark"
    >
      <Menu.Item key="/">Table View</Menu.Item>
      <Menu.Item key="/dashboard">Dashboard</Menu.Item>
    </SidebarLayout>
  );
};

export default withRouter(Sidebar);
```

// my story

```
import { storiesOf } from "@storybook/react";
import { Button } from "antd";
import React from "react";
import { MemoryRouter } from "react-router";
import Sidebar from ".";

storiesOf("Sidebar", module).add("Renders a regular menu", () => {
  return (
    <MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/"]}>
      <Sidebar />
      <Button type="primary">Button</Button>
    </MemoryRouter>
  );
});
```

// running the storybook shows this:
[outcome of running storybook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwsSC.png)

I would expect to have the AntD based component rendered in my storybook the same way it is in my CRA project:
[outcome of running CRA based project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqLya.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storybook requires default Ant Design component to be exported for styling to be applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58555019/storybook-requires-default-ant-design-component-to-be-exported-for-styling-to-be)

Answer (score 5):

Here's how I could make it work with **Storybook v6**

**Step 1:** Install a preset for Ant design. [Source](https://github.com/storybookjs/presets/tree/master/packages/preset-ant-design)

`npm i -D @storybook/preset-ant-design`

**Step 2:** In your .storybook/main.js add above preset's reference. Also note how the options of @storybook/preset-create-react-app are overrode.

```
module.exports = {
  "stories": [
    "../src/**/*.stories.mdx",
    "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"
  ],
  "addons": [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/preset-ant-design",
    {
      "name": "@storybook/preset-create-react-app",
      "options": {
        "craOverrides": {
          "fileLoaderExcludes": ["less"]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
}
```

Looks like Storybook 6.0 takes care of rest of the things and no change was required apart from these two, in my case.

Answer (score 4):

Import `antd` styles `import 'antd/dist/antd.css';` within storybook's `config.js` file:

```
// @ .storybook/config.js 
import { configure } from '@storybook/react';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';

function loadStories() {
  const req = require.context('stories', true, /\.stories\.js$/);
  req.keys().forEach(filename => req(filename));
}

configure(loadStories, module);
```

Refer to [CSS Support](https://storybook.js.org/docs/configurations/default-config/#css-support) at `storybook` docs.